# Unable to create Website using powershell in window service

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell

I Want to create a website in IIS using powershell script.I write this code in a window service.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        string sitename = "rajesh";
        //To create a New site
        //Powershell script
      string script = "cd\\\n" + "import-Module WebAdministration \n" + "IIS:\n" + "New-item iis:\\Sites\\rajesh -PhysicalPath C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\test -bindings @{Protocol='http';bindingInformation='*:8080:" + sitename + "'}" + "\n add-content C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\Hosts '127.0.0.1 " + sitename + "'";

    string s = RunScript(script);

    }

    private static string RunScript(string scriptText)
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");            
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

But when i try to start this window service in services listing...It throws an error..  The services on locat computer start and stopped.....    When i change the powershell script to  Create a folder or some small task then this window service is working but when i try to create a website through this powershell..it throws an error and window service can't be started.This powershell script is working in powershell.But not in window service..

Answer (score 0):

The error produced would be helpful.

Sitename isn't a variable either, is that atypo here or in the code?

You could try replacing the \n with ; as well, powershell doesn't use that as new line, though i guess the C# is.

Comment: Sitename is variable...For simplicity,i hardcoded here.... Yes i replaced "\n" with ";"...But it still gives the same error....But same code sucessfully runs in console application...I m not able to find the difference why it is not working in window service..

Comment: There is no error.... when i try to start window service,then it is not able to start.As i run a powershell script to create a site in Start method of window service..but when i write any other powershell code except iis site creation logic...then my window service is running perfectly

Comment: have you checked the event viewer for errors from the service?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things to note here and I think you maybe don't understand some aspects of Windows Services:

1. [`OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) is not the place to be putting any kind of logic. This event is there so you can initialise the service. For example starting a background worker thread that would run the main logic of the service and respond to external requests. For example - starting a TCP listener or initialising .NET Remoting or WCF.
2. `OnStart` is only called once when the service starts.
3. `OnStart` must return within 30 seconds although your initialisation code can [request additional time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx).

You're calling out to PowerShell and the WebAdministration add-in to create websites. Whilst this is doable, it's clunky, perhaps you should consider calling directly into the IIS7 Managed API's:

> [Microsoft.Web.Administration Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Here's an example of creating a site using the managed API's:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
  Site site = serverManager.Sites.Add("My Web Site", "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\test", 80);
  site.Bindings.Clear();
  site.Bindings.Add("*:8080:", "http");
  serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

It should also be noted that any configuration tasks performed on IIS require that the account doing this have elevated privileges i.e. be an Administrator or if it's a service run under the `SYSTEM` account.